When I parent my mesh to the rigify rig, my mesh "disappears"
When I parent my mesh to the Rigify rig, my mesh "disappears". I can see it in edit mode very, very tiny. I bought the mesh, so I don't know how it was set up, but how do I fix it?

The parenting overwrites any former parenting, so, if the previous parent had some transform values different  than 000 000 111, it can cause "jumps" in loc, rot and scale.
To solve, select the model, press Alt P > Keep transform (Clear parent), then Ctrl A > Apply Rot and Scale, then parent to the Rigify rig.
